# Enter not selecting item from JComboBox in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listener, jcombobox

I have a table with one column of JComboBoxes used for selecting from 3000 IDs from a database. I have implemented an autocomplete function into the ComboBox. When I edit a value from the combobox, and select another value with the arrow keys and press the enter key, it does not set the selected item to the highlighted item, but instead clears the box. How can I set the combo box to commit when pressing the enter key. Here is some of my code below.

```
    combo = new JComboBox(fillBox());
    AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(combo);
    InputMap map = ((JComponent) combo.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).getInputMap();
    map.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE, 0), DefaultEditorKit.deletePrevCharAction);
    ComboBoxCellEditor cellEditor = new ComboBoxCellEditor(combo);
    TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
    column.setCellEditor(cellEditor);
```

Comment: I've not tested this, but from (really foggy) memory, you may need to call [`JTable#setSurrendersFocusOnKeystroke `](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setSurrendersFocusOnKeystroke-boolean-) and pass it true, this will surrender focus to the editor component